# Android correct time format issue

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm storing a time from a time picker in a separate 'time' column in my database.

At the moment I'm using the following method of receiving and storing the selected time from the picker.:

```
setTime = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);


Integer dobHour = setTime.getCurrentHour();
Integer dobMinute = setTime.getCurrentMinute();

Time timeToSet = new Time();
timeToSet.set(0, dobMinute, dobHour);
```

Database helper object with the insert method:

```
DBHandlerApp createApp = new DBHandlerApp(this, null, null);
    createApp.open();
    createApp.createAppointmentEntry(nameToSet, typeToSet, timeToSet, setDate, comToSet, alarmToSet);
```

Method in the DB helper class:

```
    public void createAppointmentEntry(String nameApp, String typeApp, Time timeApp, Date dateApp ,String commentApp, Boolean onOrOff) {



        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_NAMEAPP, nameApp);
        cv.put(KEY_TYPEAPP, typeApp);
        cv.put(KEY_TIMEAPP, timeApp.toString());
        cv.put(KEY_DATEAPP, dateApp.toString());
        cv.put(KEY_COMMENTAPP, commentApp);
        cv.put(KEY_ALARM, onOrOff);
        ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLEAPP, null, cv);
```

In my app, the following output is showing how the date is stored:

Obviously this time format isnt correct. Can someone point me in the right direction of setting this as an actual time format.

[image: app]

Comment: Are you simply passing off the Time object to the TextView?

Comment: @A--C. Im passing the 'timeToSet object' straight to a method in my Database helper class that then inserts it. I will add that code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although Guilherme's answer works, I'd say you can also use the [Time#format()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html#format%28java.lang.String%29) method to achieve proper formatting of your time. You pass off a String to the `format()` method (eg `"%x%X"`) formatted to specifications of 
[strftime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/strftime/).

Eg

```
cv.put(KEY_TIMEAPP, timeApp.format("%x%X"));
```

This is just a default locale-specific representation, you can set it to basically anything if you want a consistent time format.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I have tried this and using '%x' i have managed to set a correct format for time. My only issue now is it always sets the time to 12:00:00am. When you say 'pass' a string, do you mean convert my time to a string? As at the moment im passing it as a 'Time' variable type.

Comment: No I mean modify the string with the %Xs to what you want based on strftime formatting. As to why it always says 12:00:00 am - I'm not actually sure.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
 public static String getDate() {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        String date = dateFormat.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        return date;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your aswer. wont this code give me the current time and not the time seelcted from my time picker?